# Clip RGB composite raster by shapefile: the process takes a very long time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip

RGB-composite raster (6,27 MB, derived from Landsat-8 band images) is clipped by a shapefile (Toolbox - Data management tools - Raster - Raster processing). It takes too long time (foreground processing shows 4% and it goes on at least 1 hour). ArcGIS 10.5.1, RAM 4 GB, Windows 7 x64. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the resolution for the output file and how complex is your shapefile?

Comment: Spatial resolution should be the same, as in the input raster (30 meters). Shapefile contains a single polygon. Actually, I was mistaken with the size of RGB-composite raster: it's 240 MB, not 6,27.

Comment: does your shapefile have a lot of nodes? Technically there is no reason that this takes so long. Have you tried to clip your Raster using GDAL?

Answer (score 1):

You might try an *Extract by mask*, to check if it works better

Comment: "Extract by mask" in Spatial Analyst tools - Extraction... works! Thank you very much!